# Why isn't the quote button working correctly here?

Tags: support, markdown

I just tried to answer [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/184615/is-there-any-command-line-tool-to-help-with-usual-tasks-that-is-cross-platform) and wanted to paste a quote from the homepage of Webmin, the software I was recommending. The exact text I wanted to quote was:

> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix. Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache, DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a system from the console or remotely. See the standard modules page for a list of all the functions built into Webmin, or check out the screenshots.

But when I pasted it in, selected it, and clicked the "Blockquote" button, I got:

---

out the screenshots.

out the screenshots.> Webmin is a web-based interface for

> system administration for Unix. Using
>   any modern web browser, you can setup
>   user accounts, Apache, DNS, file
>   sharing and much more. Webmin removes
>   the need to manually edit Unix
>   configuration files like /etc/passwd,
>   and lets you manage a system from the
>   console or remotely. See the standard
>   modules page for a list of all the
>   functions built into Webmin, or check
>   out the screenshots.out the screenshots.

---

out the screenshots.

Wow, that was even weirder here in meta, where I was trying to place that between two existing HRs. I think I'll just use the HTML for blockquote for now, but why did the blockquote button do that?

**EDIT**: I'm on Chrome 6.0.472.63 on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bug using quote button in Google Chrome on Windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/bug-using-quote-button-in-google-chrome-on-windows)

Bug in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**This <strike>is</strike> was just a test answer for me to play with this issue a bit. I can easily reproduce this issue with any text. Feel free to use this CW answer as a sandbox to test the issue yourself**

out the screenshots.

out the screenshots.> Webmin is a web-based interface for

> system administration for Unix. Using
>   any modern web browser, you can setup
>   user accounts, Apache, DNS, file
>   sharing and much more. Webmin removes
>   the need to manually edit Unix
>   configuration files like /etc/passwd,
>   and lets you manage a system from the
>   console or remotely. See the standard
>   modules page for a list of all the
>   functions built into Webmin, or check
>   out the screenshots.out the screenshots.

out the screenshots.

---

it in the form of a question.

it in the form of a question.> Please look around to see if your

> question has already been asked (and
>   maybe even answered!) before you ask.
>   It's also perfectly fine to ask and
>   answer your own question, as long as
>   you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase
>   it in the form of a question.it in the form of a question.

it in the form of a question.

---

do that?

do that?  > Wow, that was even weirder here in

> meta, where I was trying to place that
>   between two existing HRs. I think I'll
>   just use the HTML for blockquote for
>   now, but why did the blockquote button
>   do that?do that?

do that?